# DataTrigger to Update a DatePicker when a RadioButton IsChecked

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I'm simply trying to set the SelectedDate in a DatePicker based on the IsChecked of a radio button. When the radio button IsChecked is true then today's date should be entered in the DatePicker. If the IsChecked is false then the DatePicker should be null. I've tried various renditions of the data trigger but none have yielded any benefit. No matter what the radio buttons are, nothing is populated in the DatePicker. What am I missing to get this to work correctly?

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="19" Grid.Column="1" Width="120" SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedApplication.DateHireDeclineSent}"
            Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=HireDeclinedYes, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
    <DatePicker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DatePicker">                                    
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=HireDeclinedYes, Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedDate" Value="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=HireDeclinedYes, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedDate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Style>
</DatePicker>

<StackPanel Grid.Row="16" Grid.Column="4" Orientation="Horizontal"
            Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=NoHireAdd, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <RadioButton x:Name="HireDeclinedYes" Content="Yes" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedApplication.HireDeclined}" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="HireDeclinedNo" Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="No" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedApplication.HireDeclined, Converter={StaticResource BoolInverterConverter}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you remove `SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedApplication.DateHireDeclineSent}"` and set the default value using a setter:

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="19" Grid.Column="1" Width="120"
            Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=HireDeclinedYes, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
    <DatePicker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DatePicker">
            <Setter Property="SelectedDate" Value="{Binding SelectedApplication.DateHireDeclineSent}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=HireDeclinedYes, Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedDate" Value="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=HireDeclinedYes, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedDate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Style>
</DatePicker>
```

Local values take precedence over style setters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @mm8 that did the trick! I also learned something.

Answer (score 0):

Since the DatePicker *SelectedDate* is binded to `SelectedApplication.DateHireDeclineSent` and the radio button *IsChecked* property are binded to `SelectedApplication.HireDeclined` , you could, in the **setter** of SelectedApplication.HireDeclined to also change SelectedApplication.DateHireDeclineSent property and raise the property changed event?

This will change the property the DatePicker is binded to, and the property changed event will notify the view about the change, thus changing the DatePicker SelectedDate.

Just like this:

```
private bool _hireDeclined;
public bool HireDeclined
{
    get => _hireDeclined;
    set 
    {
        _hireDeclined = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("HireDeclined");
        if (//some condition)
            DateHireDeclineSent = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

private DateTime _dateHireDeclineSent;
public DateTime DateHireDeclineSent
{
    get => _dateHireDeclineSent;
    set
    {
        _dateHireDeclineSent = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DateHireDeclineSent");
    }
}
```